# Can I tell FIND_LIBRARY to run after my *custom* dependency has been built?

Tags: linux, macos, cmake, static-libraries

[Note: This is ALMOST a duplicate of [Linking to a library that hasn't been built yet with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881406/linking-to-a-library-that-hasnt-been-built-yet-with-cmake), but in this case the unbuilt library is coming from an ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET rather than an ADD_LIBRARY, so CMake can't work its usual magic so effectively.]

One of my CMake 2.8 projects currently has the following code:

```
# the COMMAND was heavily simplified but you get the idea
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(custom_breakpad_target ALL
    COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/google-breakpad && make
)

# now here we are in the root "CMakeLists.txt"
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/google-breakpad/src/client/linux)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello)
# ...many lines of code...
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(hello custom_breakpad_target)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello breakpad)
```

I know that LINK_DIRECTORIES has been deprecated (or at least disdained) because of its weird placement (it has to go before ADD_EXECUTABLE even though we'd really like to put it down next to the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES). Also, there's this nifty new command FIND_LIBRARY. So I'd like to write the root "CMakeLists.txt" more like this:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello)
# ...many lines of code...
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(hello custom_breakpad_target)
FIND_LIBRARY(breakpad breakpad ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/google-breakpad/src/client/linux)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello breakpad)
```

This code works fine... until I "make clean". The next rebuild fails to find `breakpad`, because it has been rm'ed and not created again yet by the time the FIND_LIBRARY runs.

How can I make this work? or make *something* work that's more elegant than what I've got?

---

So far, the best I've got is

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello)
# ...many lines of code...
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(hello custom_breakpad_target)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/google-breakpad/src/client/linux/libbreakpad_client.a)
```

This has the aesthetic disadvantage of having to explicitly write out the "libxxx.a" filename, whereas, as I understand it, FIND_LIBRARY would uncomplainingly continue to work even if we switched to "libxxx.1.so".

Answer (score 0):

Building external targets through custom commands is very difficult to get right. CMake offers the [`ExternalProject`](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) module to assist with that.

With this module external libraries get build at CMake configure time - that is when running `cmake` for the first time and not when running `make` to build your actual project. This has the advantage that all of the files are already in place when configuring your project, so it is easy to locate them using a find script or a [CMake configure file](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file).

This approach of course only makes sense if the external library does not change frequently, because rebuilding the library requires running CMake again. If you need to recompile the external library upon changes by just running `make`, the best way to make it work is still to write a full-fledged CMakeLists.txt for it and pull that in with `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: Are you sure? ExternalProject seems to build things at build time for me, i.e. when running make, not when running cmake. Is there an example of what you are talking about somewhere?